# ASP.NET MVC restore form element after post back to HTTP GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to restore form Data (TextBoxFor) after a post to server in Asp.Net MVC. The controller method is Get. The controller method can’t be changed to POST. The TextBoxFor control can’t be changed. When posted the form is reset and the user has to type the data again.

Thank You.

Comment: Edit the question and include your view and controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Querystring to pass the Textbox value and bound the ViewModel in the controller by assigning the Model property.